# Unable to exchange OAuth auth code for access token

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I'm just trying to make a simple app, but I can't even get past authenticating the user. I am using the Google OAuth Client Library for Java.
These are the current steps I am taking:

1. Start local web server to listen for the loopback response after the OAuth authentication.
2. Generate the auth URL:

   ```
   String url = new AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(AUTH_URL, CLIENT_ID)   
           .setScopes(scopes) // Contains https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
           .setRedirectUri(LOCALHOST + r.getPort()) // Port of local web server
           .build();
   ```
3. Use URL to authenticate account.
4. Google returns auth code.
5. Exchange auth code for access token.

   ```
   TokenResponse token = new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(...)
   .setRedirectUri("http://localhost") // <--
   .setClientAuthentication(getClientAuth()) // ClientParametersAuthentication object
   .execute();
   ```

This is where my problem occurs. No matter what value I put in for `redirect_uri`, I *always* get `{"error":"redirect_uri_mismatch","error_description":"Bad Request"}` in return.
Searching Google for the error, every single result says that it's because the `redirect_uri` I sent is not registered in the API console.
When I download the credentials json file, the `redirect_uris` section contains `"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"`, but it's all the same error no matter what I put in.

I went to the Credentials section of the project to fix it, but since this is an installed application, creating credentials for the project gives me **no** option to set any redirect uris. The only way to get access to changing redirect_uris are to create the credentials for "Web application," but this isn't a web application and I don't have a domain it can redirect to.

So I'm stuck, redirect_uri options are not available to me and no value that I use works, I honestly don't know what else to try. What steps can I take to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the same `redirect_uri` must be used for the auth code and access token even if it's not going to be used for retrieving the access token.